# Get an element from an array directly from the method call in PHP

Tags: java, php, arrays

In Java you can get an element from an array directly from the method call, like this:

```
System.out.println(PrintArrayOfStrings()[0]);
```

Is there any similar way to do this in PHP?

```
echo PrintArrayOfStrings()[0]; // Does not work!
```

Or do I always have to use a variable that first gets the array and then I use that variable to get the element?

```
$array = PrintArrayOfStrings();
echo $array[0]; // Works!
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but from the snippets you've provided it doesn't look like `System.out.println(PrintArrayOfStrings()[0]);` and `echo $myClass->PrintArrayOfStrings()[0];` are equivalent...

Comment: as k102 said, just wait php 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo PrintArrayOfStrings()[0];
```

is not possible/supported in PHP.

You can do it as you wrote:

```
$array = PrintArrayOfStrings();
echo $array[0];
```

or do it like this, if you want to have it on one line:

```
function get($array, $key){
    return $array[$key];
}
```

so then, you can use:

```
echo get(PrintArrayOfStrings(), 0);
```